# Take the average of length between times and add column query

Tags: sql-server-2008

See the below query

```
Select avg(datediff(,date1, date2)) as Avg_TOTALLengthofServicePerMember.
```

Now I want to create another query.

```
select 
    id, date1, date2, datediff(date1,date2) as Memberdiff, 
    Avg_TOTALLengthofServicePerMember
```

Outcome should be...

```
ID    Date1      Date2       Memberdiff     Avg_TOTAlLengthofServicePerMember
1      1/1/2015   1/2/2015       1               10
2      1/1/2015   1/3/2015       2               10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my best possible result that works...

```
select M1.id, M1.date1, M1.date2, avg(datediff(day, date1, date2)) as Memberdiff , (select avg(datediff(day, date1, date2)) from m) as Avg_TOTAlLengthofServicePerMember
FROM M1
GROUP BY M1.id, M1.date1, M1.date2
```